# Relationship between shuffles?

Tags: summation, permutations

Let $i$ and $j$ be two positive integers with $i<j$. A **(i, j)-shuffle** is a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1, \ldots, i+j\}$ such that $$\sigma(0)<\ldots< \sigma(i)\quad \textrm{and}\quad\sigma(i+1)<\ldots<\sigma(i+j).$$

Let us denote by $\mathsf{Sh}(i, j)$ the set of the $(i, j)$-shufles.

How can I go from a sum like $$\sum_{\sigma\in \mathsf{Sh}(i+1, j)}$$ to a sum like $$\sum_{\sigma\in \mathsf{Sh}(i, j)}?$$

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what precisely are you asking about. Inverse of a $(i, j)$-shuffle is a permutation that picks $j$ elements and puts them to the right preserving their order; it gives $|Sh(i, j)|$ =  $i+j \choose {j}$. Same considerations give explicit bijection between $Sh(i, j)$ and $Sh(i, j-1) \sqcup Sh(i-1, j)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like $\mathsf{Sh}(i, j)\simeq \mathsf{Sh}(i-1, j)\sqcup \mathsf{Sh}(j-1, i)$?

Comment: Shuffle sets have same cardinality for $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ and are conjugate in symmetric group. If you think of them not as real deck of card shuffles when you take "second" part and shufle it "into" first, but as order-preserving bijective maps $[a] \sqcup [b] \to [a+b]$ where elements of disjoin union are incomparable if they are not in same part it's obvious. Bijection is the conjugation by $(a+b)$ cycle mapping $1$ to $a+1$.